# Show Text on ProgressBar in StatusStrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar, statusstrip

I am new in **windows programming**. In C# I was working with using Visual Studio 2017. Now, Im stuck with a problem. The Problem is that, I am trying to display some text (the progress value) in `ProgressBar` in the `StatusStrip` but can't find a proper working way to do that. :-(

Can anyone please provide me some ideas or solution to this problem? I shall be glad and thankful to you !
 Your answers will be appreciated greatly. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ToolStripProgressBar` component uses a `ProgressBar` to show the progress and the  control doesn't show text. To be able to render a text for control, you need to paint the value yourself. To do so, you can create a custom item deriving from `ToolStripProgressBar`. Then you can use `NativeWindow` to assign a custom code to `WM_PAINT` message of the control:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.All)]
public class MyToolStripProgressBar : ToolStripProgressBar
{
    public MyToolStripProgressBar() : base()
    {
        this.Control.HandleCreated += Control_HandleCreated;
    }
    private void Control_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = new ProgressBarHelper((ProgressBar)this.Control);
    }
}
public class ProgressBarHelper : NativeWindow
{
    ProgressBar c;
    public ProgressBarHelper(ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        c = progressBar;
        this.AssignHandle(c.Handle);
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == 0xF /*WM_PAINT*/)
        {
            using (var g = c.CreateGraphics())
                TextRenderer.DrawText(g, c.Value.ToString(),
                   c.Font, c.ClientRectangle, c.ForeColor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, "it is no longer recommended to put text within a progress bar". By all rights correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: @P.Pat I don't see any problem in satisfying the requirement. It's a popular requirement.

Comment: I 100% agree on satisfying the requirement part. Just wanted to point out that part.

Comment: @P.Pat Yes, it's not recommended. It's stated in Windows Desktop Applications Design Guideline →[Progress Bars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742475(v=vs.85).aspx): *Don't put the percentage complete or any other text on a progress bar. Such text isn't accessible and isn't compatible with using themes.
Incorrect*

Comment: Thanks a Lot ! It worked fine :-) 
 Awesome Technique !

Comment: And @P.Pat thanks for pointing out that it is not recommended .. Learnt something new :-) |
 But I dont want to use it as a progressbar there. I am just learning windows forms and wanted to use it to display Image Size Percentage (Compared to original size) :-)

Comment: Yes @RezaAghaei It works fine ... and I understood your code because I have already dealed with window messages through Window Procedure ! 
 But I didn't now that we can do this in C# too. Thanks again Sir :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Some times you can derive from controls and override their `WndProc`. Sometimes you don't want or you can't derive from the control and you just want to extend message handling without inheritance, in such cases a `NativeWindow` would be fine.

Comment: But Sir .... Can you please tell? What does this statement mean? :-) 
[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.All)]

Comment: Using [`ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161735.aspx) you can specify the component be available for `MenuStrip`, `ContextMenuStrip`, `ToolStrip`, `StatusStrip` or a combination of them or all of them.

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't even know you could do this! Overriding the WndProc of a control without inheritance!? Upvoted for awesomeness.

Answer (score 3):

```
  progressBar1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(progressBar1.Value.ToString(), new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - 10, progressBar1.Height / 2 - 7));
```

I had the same question just a jew days ago an ran into this little piece of code that does the job perfectly :)
Got the code and explanation from [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/62979-add-the-percent-into-a-progress-bar/) Website

Comment: I did not, did you got an issue with that?

Comment: Does it give you an error or something else? can you show how you embedded it?

Comment: May be I was Implementing it in a wrong way. Although I got the solution. But I think I had to use your code while overriding OnPaint() event handler. :-) Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (and perhaps some earlier versions)

- **Click on the status bar** in the form designer.
- Click the small **drop down arrow** to the right of the status bar elements.
- Select the **Progress bar** item.

A class of type `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar` is created with a name like **toolStripProgressBar1**.

Items can be deleted from the status bar by selecting them and clicking **delete**.