# Alphanumeric Textbox - Validate/Sanitize clipboard text before paste

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

On my `Textbox` only accepts Alphanumeric characters and a underscore using the `Keypressed` event but I am having problems when I right click on the textbox and pasted special characters and accepts it

[image]

Is there a way to validate the string from there before clicking paste?

Any answers will help thanks!

Comment: Try `TextChanged` event

Comment: I edited my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may

1- Disable shortcuts for the textbox that would disable Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, and the second line(will assign a empty context menu, with no items and will override the original context menu) and no context menu will appear (as it has no items):

```
textBox1.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
textBox1.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
```

2-If you don't want to disable paste option, you may use `TextChanged` event of the textbox and validate the pasted text there.

Comment: Thanks sir but I need to take option 2.

Answer (score 2):

`TextChanged` is a bit late, it raises after the text of the control has been changed and results in an awkward user experience.

To have a better user experience, it's better to handle `WM_PASTE` message and strip disallowed characters and paste the sanitized test on `SelectedText`.
`TextChanged` event is a bit late and the user experience is not friendly enough, it removes the character after te text property changes which is annoying. By handling `WM_PASTE` and `OnKeyPress` you can always keep the caret at the position which is expected by user, sanitize input without any flicker.

**Alphanumeric TextBox**

Here is an example which allows alphanumeric characters and underscore for a `TextBox`. On key press, if the character is not allowed, it plays a beep sound. In paste, if the string contains disallowed characters, it strips the characters and paste just valid characters:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool MessageBeep(int type);
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg != WM_PASTE) { base.WndProc(ref m); }
        else
        {
            var text = SanitizeText(Clipboard.GetText());
            SelectedText = text;
        }
    }
    protected virtual string SanitizeText(string value)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(value ?? "", @"[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", "");
    }
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        var input = e.KeyChar;
        var allowedChars = new char[] { '_', '\b' };
        if (((ModifierKeys & (Keys.Control | Keys.Alt)) != 0) |
            Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) |
            allowedChars.Contains(input))
        {
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBeep(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also change the `SanitizeText` method to do just validation to prevent paste rather than sanitizing input. I prefer sensitization, it's more natural IMO.

Comment: sir how do I use the WndProc? is it supposed to be like a method?

Comment: What I've created is a new class called `MyTextBox` which is derived from `TextBox`. Create a new file and paste above code into the file. Rebuild your project and then drop an instance of `MyTextBox` from toolbox onto your form.

Comment: I have tried using `public class MyTextBox : Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuMaterialTextbox` but I am having problems with `SelectedText  = text` , it says does not exist in current context. btw Im using Bunifu framework. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `SelectedText` is a property of the `TextBox` which gets or sets a value indicating the currently selected text in the control. If your base class is something else, you may want to ask banifu support about such property or if it is a wrapper around a text box standard control, you can set `SelectedText` property of the wraped text box control. For example it may be a custom control having a textBox property, then you can have access to `textBox.SelectedText`.

Comment: In addition, if the banifu text box is not deriving from text box, then in `WndProc` of the control, you will not receive `WM_PASTE`, instead you need to use `NativeWindow` to handle the messages for the wrapped text box control. It's the way of handling messages for another control without being able to overrode its WndProc, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139254/3110834).

Comment: Anyway, it's better to keep this thread dedicated to `TextBox` control as it's more popular and the question is talking about `TextBox`. You may want to ask another question about how to apply such thing to banifu text box.