# Block Paste event in a DomainUpDown control

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a custom DomainUpDown. I need to block the Paste event.

I tried to override the control's `WndProc`, which works fine in a MaskedTextBox but here it doesn't work.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x302)  //PasteEvent
    {
        //base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    else
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `NativeWindow` you can handle messages of the inner `TextBox` which is used in `DomainUpDown` and `NumericUpDown` controls.

In the follwowing code, I've handled `WM_PASTE` method and just played a beep in response:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyDomainUpDown : DomainUpDown
{
    MyWindoHelper wh;
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        wh = new MyWindoHelper(Controls[1]);
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (wh != null)
            wh.DestroyHandle();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    class MyWindoHelper : NativeWindow
    {
        Control c; //For future reference if needed.
        public MyWindoHelper(Control control)
        {
            c = control;
            this.AssignHandle(c.Handle);
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg != 0x0302 /*WM_PASTE*/)
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            else
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

If you may want to validate the input and paste a sanitized text to the control, take a look at the following post:

- [Textbox - Validate input before paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53681247/3110834)

Comment: Like it :) In UI Automation-style, the control could be `wh = new MyWindoHelper(Controls.OfType<Control>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.AccessibilityObject.Role == AccessibleRole.Text));` I have the VS IDE now :)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, it works very well, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you can set the handle of the control, the `Message.hWnd` reference, to `IntPtr.Zero`: the message won't be delivered.

This doesn't apply to the **`DomainUpDown`** control: it doesn't receive a `WM_PASTE` message, just a `WM_COMMAND`. Setting the Handle reference to `IntPtr.Zero` is useless, the Control that is processing the messages is the child **`UpDownEdit`** control (`TextBox` derived).

A possible solution:
Disable `Control-V`, `Shift-Insert` and the `ContextMenu` on a Right-MouseDown:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
{
    if ((keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.V)) || (keyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Insert))) {
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

ContextMenu emptyMenu = new ContextMenu();

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
        this.ContextMenu = emptyMenu;
        return;
    }
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && this.emptyMenu != null) {
        this.emptyMenu.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: Well, it depends. It works with most controls. What is a `domainUpDown`? Do you mean a `NumericUpDown`?

Comment: it's almost the same as the numericUpDown, in visual studio there are both controls

Comment: All right. You could also hook the underlying edit control of the `DomainUpDown` using UI Automation. Then you can do anything with it. But you must be quite confortable with UI Automation to, eventually, change/adapt something (headaches are lurking there).

Comment: You may want to store and reuse `ContextMenu` and dispose it on dispose of the control.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei  Of course, thanks. Updated. Thing is, I don't like this method very much. The OP should pick what you proposed, it's more *educational*.