# How to limit textbox to accept only specific characters

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, character

I wanted to know How to limit number of specific character of a textbox in c# form application.
for example i want to limit the user to enter `-` (*minus*) *only one time* and then if he try to input again I want the program to restrict inputing that again.

**Examples:** `-123` or `123-` or `123-123` (*only one* `-`).

If user *remove* `-` then should have permission to input one `-` again and of course no more!

I want to *prevent* user to enter `----1234` or `1234--`, or `123-4--21` or what more you think!!

Here is what I'm trying:

```
private void txtStopAfterXTimes_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemMinus || e.KeyCode == Keys.Subtract)
    {
        if (txtStopAfterXTimes.Text.Count((char)'-', 1))
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        else if (txtStopAfterXTimes.Text.Count((char)'-', 0))
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = false;
        }
    }
}
```

i know it's wrong but please help!
thank you...

Comment: `e.SuppressKeyPress = txtStopAfterXMinutes.Text.Count(c => c == '-') > 0` ?

Comment: sorry i had mistakes in post text so i edited that!

Comment: i tried : e.SuppressKeyPress = txtStopAfterXTimes.Text.Count(c => c == '-') > 0; but not worked. can you please describe what your code does?

Comment: it counts `-` characters in `txtStopAfterXMinutes.Text` and if there more then 0, it sets `e.SuppressKeyPress` to false

Comment: I'd use something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53681247/3110834) because you need to care about paste as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `Text` within `txtStopAfterXTimes` by **2** ways: *pressing* a key (`-`) or by *pasting* a value.
That's why we have to handle **2** events: `KeyPress` for `-` key pressing and `TextChanged` for text pasting:

**Code:** (WinForms)

```
private void txtStopAfterXTimes_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // When pasting a text into txtStopAfterXTimes...
  TextBox box = sender as TextBox;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(box.Text.Length);

  bool containsMinus = false;

  // We remove all '-' but the very first one
  foreach (char ch in box.Text) {
    if (ch == '-') {
      if (containsMinus)
        continue;

      containsMinus = true;
    }

    sb.Append(ch);
  }

  box.Text = sb.ToString();
}

private void txtStopAfterXTimes_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  TextBox box = sender as TextBox;

  // we allow all characters ...
  e.Handled = e.KeyChar == '-' &&             // except '-'
              box.Text.Contains('-') &&       // when we have '-' within Text
             !box.SelectedText.Contains('-'); // and we are not going to remove it
}
```

Comment: sorry, my programming is not much good as you so im just got confused! :| can you please give me a more simple way if possible ? thanks for your help but i want to know both ways thank you.

Comment: handling 2 events instead of 1?

Comment: @vasily.sib: yes, we have to handle `2` event: 1. to prevent second `-` when user *presses* `-` key; 2. to prevent many `-` (remove all but the very first one) when user *pastes* a text

Comment: sorry, can you please describe this section: foreach (char ch in box.Text) {
    if (ch == '-') {
      if (containsMinus)
        continue;

      containsMinus = true;
    }

    sb.Append(ch);
  }       i mean how it works...

Comment: @hamidrezas120: we scan pasted text (`box.Text`) if we get `-` (ch == '-') we should decide wether to *take* it or *skip* it (`continue`) if we've taken `-` before (`if (containsMinus)`) we omit the minus; if it's the 1st `-` we take it but mark (`containsMinus = true;`) that we have `-` and we should skip all the other minuses

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I mean why do you need to handle `KeyPress` if `TextChanged` will be called after it anyway?

Comment: if (containsMinus) means: if (containsMinus == true)??

Comment: @vasily.sib: 1. When preventing second `-` by pressing `-` I want to keep caret position (i.e. `SelectionStart`, `SelectionLength`). 2. Minus can be removed in *different* ways (e.g. we can remove all the minuses but the *last* one)

Comment: @hamidrezas120: yes `if (containsMinus)` is a shorter form of `if (containsMinus == true)`

Comment: one last question: `continue;` skips the whole foreach? or `if (ch == '-')`? or `if (containsMinus)`?

Comment: hamidrezas120: *once started* (after the 1st `-` is taken and `containsMinus` is set to `true`) skips continue the entire `foreach`

Comment: i used what you said and for example: after i enter `1` then `-` then `2` then again `-` then selection start will go at start of textbox so i added this line of code in last line of textchanged event and it's now fixed :D : txtStopAfterXTimes.SelectionStart = txtStopAfterXTimes.Text.Length;

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I don't know if I got confused here, or I am simply misunderstanding something, but `continue` continues the `foreach` with the next element. A `break` would skip the rest of the `foreach` (ie "break out of the loop").

Comment: @waka: quite right: we `continue` looping (i.e. ask for the next character from `box.Text`) instead of appending `ch` to `StringBuilder sb`

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid using `TextChanged` because it will be raised after the text has changed and it may be a bit late.

This is the solution which I will use, because you also need to care about paste.

- On `keyPress` I check if the character is not the first "-", then I'll ignore it, otherwise I'll accept it.
- On `WndProc` I catch `WM_PASTE` and sanitize the clipboard text, by removing all occurrences of "-" but the first one. You can also easily decide to stop pasting if the input is not acceptable.

Here is the implementation:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool MessageBeep(int type);
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg != WM_PASTE) { base.WndProc(ref m); }
        else {
            //You can sanitize the input or even stop pasting the input
            var text = SanitizeText(Clipboard.GetText());
            SelectedText = text;
        }
    }
    protected virtual string SanitizeText(string value)
    {
        if (Text.IndexOf('-') >= 0) { return value.Replace("-", ""); }
        else {
            var str = value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf("-") + 1);
            return str + value.Substring(str.Length).Replace("-", "");
        }
    }
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '-' && this.Text.IndexOf('-') >= 0) {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBeep(0);
        }
        else {
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
        }
    }
}
```